# Open a file for RawIOBase python

Tags: python, binary

I need to read in the the binary of a file for a function, and from this link https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html, it looks like I should be using a RawIOBase object to read it in. But I can't find any where on how to open a file to use with RawIOBase. Right now I have tried this to read the binary into a string

```
with (open(documentFileName+".bin", "rb")) as binFile:
    document = binFile.RawIOBase.read()

print document
```

but that throws the error AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'RawIOBase'

So with no open attribute in RawIOBase, how do I open the file for it to read from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't delve into the implementation details of the `io` thicket unless you need to code your own peculiar file-oid-like types!  In your case,

```
with open(documentFileName+".bin", "rb") as binFile:
    document = binFile.read()
```

will be perfectly fine!

Note in passing that I've killed the superfluous parentheses you were using -- "no unneeded pixels!!!" -- but, while important!, that's a side issue to your goal here.

Now, assuming Python 2, `document` is a `str` -- an immutable array of bytes.  It may be confusing that displaying `document` shows it as a string of characters, but that's just Py2's confusion between text and byte strings (in Py3, the returned type would be `bytes`).

If you prefer to work with (e.g) a mutable array of `int`s, use e.g

```
 theints = map(ord, document)
```

or, for an immutable array of bytes that displays numerically,

```
 import array
 thearray = array.array('b', document)
```

Comment: Okay, make sense. But I think I've mis represented my question, I'm looking to read the individual bits of a file into a binary string. When I open the file with open('filename','rb') I simply get back an ascii representation of the string. Is there a speciality function to read the individual bytes?

Comment: Editing to, I hope, clarify your confusion (assuming Python 2 from the URL you give -- it **would** be nice to tag appropriately...).